# How to run Quicken 6 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 16-bit, quicken

My dad has been using Quicken 6 for years and has moved to a new Windows 10 laptop.

He'd like to continue using it.

He has the original CDs but no CD ROM on the new laptop. Also, it's 16-bit software and may not even run on Windows 10.

What's my best course of action to run Quicken 6 / 16-bit software on a Windows 10 laptop?

Answer (score 2):

**Running 16 bit programs**

Windows 10 64 bit will not run 16 bit programs while Windows 10 32 bit will run 16 bit programs if you [enable NTVDM](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-16-bit-application-support-windows-10/) in *Windows Features*.

You can check if you are running 64 or 32 bit by looking in *System > About* as described here : [How Do I Know if I’m Running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21726/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-answers/)

If you are running 64 bit you could download Windows 10 32 bit using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) which will put it on a blank USB for you and then use this to do a clean install as described in this [Tenforums tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html).

Note that 32-bit Windows can not address more than 4GB or RAM so if your PC has more than this the extra RAM would not be available and also that a clean install will remove all your programs and data.

If this is an issue you could either install Windows 10 32 bit in a Virtual Machine or upgrade Quicken.

**Obtaining Quicken**

If you do not have a DVD drive you could buy an external one from [around $10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QM6XLM0) or try to contact Quicken support for a download link.  Although they do not mention Quicken 6 it may be worth an attempt.

See [How do I install Quicken from a CD if I don't have a CD/DVD drive?](https://www.quicken.com/support/how-do-i-install-quicken-cd-if-i-do-not-have-cddvd-drive).

> **If you have a computer without a CD drive and you purchased Quicken on CD (Quicken 2016 and 2017)**
>
> We can provide you with a download of Quicken to install. Just have your proof of purchase ready (such as the Order Number emailed to you), and [Contact Support](https://www.quicken.com/support#contact-support). Scroll down to the bottom of the Quicken Support page for our phone number and chat options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run 16-bit software on a 64-bit Windows machine (and the vast majority of Windows 10 machines are 64-bit). I have 16-bit machines here (virtual) and the software / connections do not run on 64-bit bit. Truly the best way is to upgrade Quicken. The second best way is to use an expired operating system. I recommend upgrading Quicken to a newer version  (Quicken 2019 is available now)

https://www.quicken.com/canada/ppc/win/nf?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=g_s_brand_beta_canada&gclid=CjwKCAiAh5_uBRA5EiwASW3IaiEGlB4uLO9TTB-8aywlBt9R4TRtjhc0TlyC3InO9j2E1x0EkYY4_BoCbwIQAvD_BwE

Lucy - you should check with your Dad. Assuming the Laptop is 64-bit, changing to 32-bit means backing everything up, reinstalling Windows and then limited to 3 GB of memory. Using a Virtual Machine (something I do) is not really for the average consumer and you would need to acquire a new Windows 10 license for this. So really, upgrading Quicken as earlier suggested is the best long term solution here –

Comment: "*There is no way to run 16-bit software on a 64-bit machine.*" - I think you mean there is no way to run 16-bit programs on 64-bit **Windows**.  You can run 16-bit programs on 32-bit Windows 10 (even if processor is 64-bit) if you [enable NTVDM](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-16-bit-application-support-windows-10/).

Comment: @lx07 your comment should be an answer

Comment: @Moab - I think this is a better solution but I will post the alternative of installing Windows 32bit as an alternative.

Comment: Post both solutions please